# Why is this application never a top hit on Spotlight?

Tags: applications, spotlight

I've installed the Winbox4Mac application from [here](http://joshaven.com/resources/tools/winbox-for-mac/). It is a Windows application packaged to run with Wine.

It appears to look for all the world like any other valid (albeit non-codesigned) application bundle, and I can run it directly from the Finder like any other application once I've accepted the Gatekeeper prompt. However, no matter what I do, Spotlight will always preference anything else (especially web search) over it for Top Hit:

[image: screenshot of spotlight preferring a web search over an application]

To my knowledge, no other application on my computer shares this behaviour.
I've tried:

- renaming the application and waiting for Spotlight to reindex it (no effect)
- verifying that Spotlight doesn't demote non-signed applications from Top Hit (it doesn't)

Comment: Because you haven't indicated this, have you tried typing in WinBox and choosing the application a few times? Spotlight should learn to use the application if you do this.

Comment: @EzekielElin I tried this just now at least ten times, no change unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

## What the..

It's a regression in Spotlight.
It worked correctly on Mojave; since the upgrade to Catalina & Monterey the sorting is messed up and it doesn't learn from user choices.
It always gives web results as first (Apple.... I have a browser for that.. ) and dismisses local results to 4th-10th position .

The app *DeepL*, that I usually open every 15 minutes or so, was always a top hit because of the frequency of use. Now, after the macOS update, it never makes it to the first choices.

### But...

.. *DeepL Uninstall*, that of course I **never** hit, always shows as a first choice on Spotlight, no matter how many hundreds of times I've opened *DeepL* via <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
Seriously Apple, what's the logic in that? It's a regression of past behaviour.

## Workaround

Add a tag to the file/app you want to prioritise; whatever tag.
This will bump the result a little.

At least, it managed to select the application instead of its installer.
Doesn't solve the bug but hopefully it mitigates the issue.